# Select * from table not working SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select all records from a table and then output them below, however I am only able to get the most recent output out.

The table structure is Id, Start, End, DistanceDirections and Date

I am using the code below to get them and then output each Start as a H1 on the page. As mentioned I am only getting the last value out not all as I would expect, I have also tried to be more specific which can be seen in the code below that and it didn't have an effect on the result.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `searchdata`";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

foreach($stmt as $row) {
    $htmlResult = "<h1>" . $row['Start'] . "</h1>";
}
```

Here is the other try:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `searchdata` WHERE DistanceDirections = 'distance'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

foreach($stmt as $row) {
    $htmlResult = "<h1>" . $row['Start'] . "</h1>";
}
```

Is there something simple I am missing?

Comment: which MySQL API are you using to connect with? `mysqli_`, or PDO?

Comment: PDO is what I am using

Comment: Ok. That could've swung for `mysqli_`. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only executing the query, you'll also need to fetch the rows.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `searchdata`";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

$htmlResult = "";
foreach($result as $row) {
    $htmlResult .= "<h1>" . $row['Start'] . "</h1>";
}

echo $htmlResult;
```

More info:http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Still only getting the last result in the database.

Comment: @LewisSmith Changed my answer, try that.

Comment: You're overwriting `$htmlResult` in each iteration. It now appends.